# How can I install Ubuntu 12.04 on external HDD?

Tags: 12.04

I used to install Ubuntu 11.10 on my external HDD, it was working well, but after I installed 12.04 on my external HDD, it can't boot any more!

Answer (score 1):

just go through the same process you did for 11.10. You would just choose erase entire disk. you'll loose files though so I would click try Ubuntu and see if you could move any wanted files to a thumb drive or something.

Comment: the upgrade process has proven to cause similar issues.

Comment: I installed 12.04 by using the live CD, and I did choose erase entire disk.

Comment: Sorry you made it sound like you used the upgrade manager. I guess try reinstalling it, or make sure you computer's bios boot order is still usb/cd/dvd (can't remember quite what it is) is at the top level, above internal hdd. try the second idea first.

Comment: my guess is when you changed the order of where to boot from, I'm assuming this, that boot from usb got pushed to the bottom.

Comment: I'm sure it was boot from usb, because the whole screen has gone purple, and there is no hard disk in my computer. it knows there is a system in the external HDD, and it was booting from the external HDD, but somehow, it decided eject all the usb device, i can hear my external HDD stop running,and then it gone black, shows me something "doesn't exist".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sort of problem.  I have a Windows 7 laptop with an external HDD connected via USB.  When I partitioned the external HDD and installed Ubuntu 12.10, it would not boot even when USB HDD was first in BIOS boot ordering.  I reinstalled with one change to make it work.  I chose to install GRUB on the internal HDD.  I have to choose a boot option everytime now, even if I am booting into Windows 7 with the USB HDD disconnected.  However, this is a small price to pay for this functionality.

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how you installed GRUB to help the OP?